# Why does adding these constants to my template vars keep me logged in?

Tags: django

I wrote a wrapper around `render_to_response` that looks like this

```
from app import constants

def response(request, template, vars={}):
    if '.' not in template:
        template += '.html'
    template_vars = {}

    for constant in dir(constants):
        if constant[:2] == '__': continue
        template_vars[constant] = getattr(constants, constant) # BUG: causes you to stay logged in
    template_vars.update({'settings':settings})
    template_vars.update({'request':request})
    template_vars.update(vars)

    return render_to_response(template, template_vars, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It seems that by adding the constants to the template vars, `user.is_authenticated` always returns true in the template, and `user.username` gets its value from some random user (most recently registered or something). Just wondering why that is?

Anyone care to explain?

If I print the constants, these are them

```
BidReasons
BidStatuses
CA_PROVINCES
COUNTRIES
CancellationRequestStatuses
EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS
Enum
Flags
InvoiceStatuses
NA_REGIONS
PaymentMethods
PaymentTimes
PaymentTypes
SELECT_OPTION
SecretKeyPurposes
Sequence
ServiceTypes
ShipmentStatuses
USER_RATINGS
US_STATES
VehicleListingOptions
WeekDays
YES_OR_NO
```

I don't see anything in there that would mess with `user`

---

My new fix, if curious:

```
def response(request, template, vars={}):
    if '.' not in template:
        template += '.html'

    template_vars = {'settings':settings, 'request':request, 'constants':constants.__dict__}
    template_vars.update(vars)

    return render_to_response(template, template_vars, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: why are you assigning constants.__dict__ to template_vars, updating it twice, then reassigning it to vars?  I don't think it is causing a problem, it just stands out.

Comment: How are you using this function?  It sounds like it could potentially be a thread-safely issue, like you're passing a different request into the template and overriding the "request" from your RequestContext.

Comment: @Matthew: Oops...that was residue from when I was trying to figure out what the heck was going wrong :p I'm using it at the end of almost every view func... in place of `render_to_response`.

Comment: @Matthew: Actually... that was what was fixing it, not my removal of that `'request':request` bit. Turns out the real problem is the `constants.__dict__` part... let me update

Answer (score 1):

Not really related to your question, but if you want to add variables to your template context, rather than calling a separate function in each view you might want to look into [context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) which do the same thing automatically.

Comment: Hrm... didn't think about that. Good suggestion! I still wanted to get rid of that nasty `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` bit though. It used to use a default template based on the view func name too...but that didn't pan out.